# How to set the volume of audio player to a default 20% on my flash web page

Tags: flash, actionscript-2, audio-player

I need to have my audio player start with a default 20% than 100%. I tried to deduct some digits in the related actionscript and all I did was set the entire bar to 20%... I even tried to pull the volume backward but that's not the way it works. (I'm not a coder btw.. I just play with codes to understand how they work)

I guess it has something to do with the actionscript below but in case that I'm wrong, I also attached the source .fla...

```
//
// SOUND CONTROL COMPONENT
//
// Initial Settings
//
originY = volBttn._y;
originX = volBttn._x;
maxX = scrollBar._width-volBttn._width;
eq_mc.gotoAndStop(Math.round(1+(_global.volumeAmount/20)));
hover_mc._visible = false;
// Equaliser
doEQ = function () {
    eq_mc.eq_all._yscale = _global.volumeAmount;
};
resetSlider = function () {
    volBttn._x = Math.round((scrollBar._width-volBttn._width)*(_global.volumeAmount/100));
};
// Volume button onPress
volBttn.onPress = function() {
    this.startDrag(0, 0, originY, maxX, originY);
    hover_mc.onEnterFrame = function() {
        _global.volumeAmount = Math.round((volBttn._x/(scrollBar._width-volBttn._width))*100);
        doEQ();
        this.txt.text = _global.volumeAmount+"%";
        this.txt._width = this.txt.textWidth+10;
        this.bg._width = this.txt._width+10;
        this._x = volBttn._x+volBttn._width/2;
        this._y = volBttn._y;
        hover_mc._visible = true;
    };
};
// Volume button onRelease
volBttn.onRelease = volBttn.onReleaseOutside=function () {
    delete hover_mc.onEnterFrame;
    this.stopDrag();
    hover_mc._visible = false;
    this.gotoAndPlay('rollOut');
};
volBttn.onRollOver = function() {
    this.gotoAndPlay('rollOver');
};
```

I also can't increase or decrease the volume by clicking on the navigator bar. I have to click and hold that small navigator and then drag it to left or right. It makes it a bit difficult not to mention that there's no mute button. How may I fix it ?

http://www.mediafire.com/download/3olq6jthewr5t26/index.rar

Comment: You have just to change this `_global.volumeAmount = 100;` to `_global.volumeAmount = 20;`.

Comment: @akmozo I changed all the digits in there but the only thing that seems to change is the length of the navigation bar to 20% from this line:                _global.volumeAmount = Math.round((volBttn._x/(scrollBar._width-volBttn._width))*100);

Comment: You should not touch the other code, only the instruction that I told you which initialize the `volumeAmount` global var.

Comment: I do understand what you meant. I tried changing every single digits and exporting them one by one but none of them worked. maybe that's not the right piece of code. anyways the source is right there on my first post. it would be great if you could take a look and see what is wrong. Thanks

Comment: What I meant is that you have to change only this line : `_global.volumeAmount = 100;` to `_global.volumeAmount = 20;`, that's all, that should do the job, of course you have to reset other values.

Comment: @akmozo like I said I DID understand what you meant. (though there's no " = " in the code I put there) I tried every single possibility but none of them worked and beside even if I managed to turn the volume down to 20%, there's another issue. the volume slider is set to its default full length. I finally had to put a sample bundle... there are two indexes.. index20 (exactly like you said) and index100 (the default index).. both have the same volume. play it and hear for yourself. BTW, the source is also included.. you could export yours and put it there and see if you can hear any changes.

Comment: here's the link BTW: http://www.mediafire.com/download/3z2tzdpajtw4cdh/Sample.rar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decompiled your two swf files : index20.swf and index100.swf, but you didn't what I meant because in both of them I find :

```
...

// it's the 89th line of the 1st frame of your main timeline, here you should put 20
_global.volumeAmount = 100;      
_global.volSaved = "";

...
```

So to get your swf working as you want, you should set :

```
_global.volumeAmount = 20;
```

And then in your `soundControl_mc.volume_mc` MovieClip you have to execute the `resetSlider()` and `doEQ()` functions to set the initial position of the volume slider and initilize the equalizer, you should call them after their definitions of course if you are in the timeline of `soundControl_mc.volume_mc` or after setting `_global.volumeAmount` in the main timeline :

```
resetSlider();
doEQ();
```

Which will give you something like this :

[image]

You can download your project [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/54vd9vf525vvsyq/Sample.zip).

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thank you so much akmozo... I should have guessed,I put the wrong piece of code in there. the amount to change was in the "scene 1" not in "the eq_sound_mc". everything's workin perfectly fine however the sound keeps looping when I add more than two sounds. I'm not sure if making these changes has anything to do with looping. have I done sth wrong ?! I never noticed this before. Now that you have the source would you please see what's wrong?

Comment: @S.T.A.R.S What do you mean by "looping" ?

Comment: I mean the sound keeps repeating itself when it finishes playing them all.

Comment: @S.T.A.R.S I have edited some lines which has nothing to do with looping the playlist. Verify your `playlist_mc.player_mc.doForward` function which do the looping :` if (ID<total-1) { ID++; } else { ID = 0; }`.

Comment: My bad  akmozo. I just thought that it was related. anyway I found the code mentioned. could you please tell me how to edit it so that it stops looping ? I tried to set the ID to 1 (ID=1) and it just looped the second sound. I don't really feel like asking a new question for this minor issue.

Comment: @S.T.A.R.S You have just to remove the `else` and change your `if` to `if (ID<total-1) { ID++;  doHighlight(); loadTrack(); }`.